# Useful Boilerplate for NextJS, NextAuth, Cognito, and Hasura

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, next-auth, hasura

I'm trying to start a new project using Hasura/GraphQL. I have used NextJS before, and now I'm trying to incorporate Cognito. I have everything set up for Hasura and Cognito, and the login works, custom claims work, the JWT looks correct, and some of the Next pages with requests to Hasura work. But it all falls apart when I try to use a subscription via Apollo. None of the tutorials or documentation show a clear way to use websockets with the current libraries. Hasura docs use previous "not recommended libraries," or other tutorials use NextAuth directly with Hasura for authentication.

It seems like it would be a common use case to outsource OAuth to Cognito and not worry about JWT creation or anything like that.

To be honest, the first thing I tried when I ran into walls was ChatGPT 4. It helped a little, but as it says in their documentation, it only knows up to late 2021. All the current libraries have changed (e.g., don't use subscriptions-transport-ws, use graphql-ws). It's just another level of dependency hell for me.

Here's what I have working:
Apollo client:

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "<HASURA_URL_HERE>",
});

const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  const session = await getSession();
  const token = session?.idToken;

  const h = {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ""
    },
  };
  console.log("headers", h, session);
  return h;
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

_app.js

```js
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import { SessionProvider, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import theme from "../theme";
import createEmotionCache from "../theme/createEmotionCache";
import Head from "next/head";
import HeaderBar from "@/components/HeaderBar";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import client from "../lib/apolloClient";

// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={clientSideEmotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <HeaderBar />
            {Component.auth ? (
              <Auth>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              </Auth>
            ) : (
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            )}
          </ApolloProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

function Auth({ children }) {
  // if `{ required: true }` is supplied, `status` can only be "loading" or "authenticated"
  const { status } = useSession({ required: true });

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return children;
}
```

pages/event.js

```js
import EventsRow from "@/components/Events/EventsRow";
import EventsRowHeader from "@/components/Events/EventsRowHeader";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_EVENTS_QUERY = gql`
  query GetEvents {
    events {
      id
      name
      eventDate
    }
  }
`;

export default function Events() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_EVENTS_QUERY);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  const events = data.events;

  return (
    <div>
      <EventsRowHeader />
      {events.map((e) => (
        <EventsRow key={e.id} event={e} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

All that works:
[image]

(Further proving my point on the JWT, there are 2 events there which are "owned" by my user ID, which means not only are the hasura custom claims working, but the hasura permissions tied to the user role and my user Id are working as well. There are 5 events in the database, but I can only see those as this user).

But as soon as I change that gql from a query to a subscription (which works in the Hasura Graphiql UI) and change useQuery to useSubscription, I get:
`Error: subscriptions are not supported over HTTP, use websockets instead`

Ok, so back to the documentation. I have to split lib/apolloClient.js to detect if it's server side or client side, but also to split out the request, like this:

```js
const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription';
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
);
```

But now that's using a different library than I was using before, and both don't work together...

I say *all* of this to say... Isn't this a standard use case? Does anybody have an example they can point me to to just be able to use Hasura with a valid token in NextJS?

I would be glad to join an open source project to put together this boilerplate if I could then fork it for my projects...